# .net Webbrowser scraper data not coming in web completed event

Tags: .net, ajax, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I am trying to automate a webbrowser in .net. It extracts data from a web page. Here is the code in the completed event:

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = e.Url.ToString();
            if (!(url.StartsWith("http://") || url.StartsWith("https://")))
            {
                // in AJAX
            }

            if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != this.wb.Url.AbsolutePath)
            {
                // IFRAME 
            }
            else
            {
                // REAL DOCUMENT COMPLETE
                txtLogger.Text += "Loaded";
                txtLogger.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                if (url.Contains("VendorRequisitionDetail"))
                {
                    HtmlElement elem = wb.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_contplhDynamic_VenReqDetSubmission_Reqdiv");

                    lstData.Add(elem.InnerText);
                    elem = wb.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_contplhDynamic_VenReqDetSubmission_lblSubMaxSub");
                    lstData.Add(elem.InnerText);

                    dt.Rows.Add(lstData[0], lstData[1], string.Empty);
                    if (frmData != null)
                    {
                        frmData.Refresh();
                    }

                    counter++;
                    lstData.Clear();
                    wb.GoBack();
                }
                else if (url.Contains("Requisition/List"))
                {
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        if (counter < count)
                        {

                            he = wb.Document.GetElementById("RequisitionGrid");
                            if (he == null) return;

                            requisitionIdCollection = he.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
                            hlink = requisitionIdCollection[counter].Children[13].GetElementsByTagName("a")[1];
                            hlink.InvokeMember("click");
                        }
                        else if (counter == count)
                        {
                            IsScraped = true;
                            txtLogger.Text += "Scraped";
                            txtLogger.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                            count = 0;
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is I am not getting data. The webpage loads and completed event fires. But webpage loads data after sometime using some type of AJAX. What website do is it loads the page and first displays loading message. The webbrowser completed event fires and loading message I can extract. Now the website loads some data. I cannot get any completed event for this loading of data.
How can I get the loaded data ? Sorry for bad english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional Check:

```
if(!wb.IsBusy)
{}
```